# Center a row of images with no padding between them in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row of images set up using simple bootstrap:

```
<div class="row top-shows">
    <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 hiden-xs hiden-sm"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 hiden-xs hiden-sm"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div>
</div>
```

This works fine when I want them to be evenly spaced, but I don't want them evenly spaced. I want them to be stuck side by side and the entire row to be centered. So only the first and last images are padded. How would I do this?

Also note that the last 2 images disappear on `xs` screens with the `hidden-xs` class.

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://www.bootply.com/QXNY7rStwc ?

Comment: @PatrickLC not quite, because when the last two images get hidden, the remaining to not resize. Nice fix tho, but no sigar :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid additional markup in your HTML (hint: you should) you might want to try something like this:

## [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zfh6Lmb/1/)

Specifically, this class on your row: `.rem-margin-children`

and add this CSS to your site's CSS file:

```
.rem-space-children > * {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

## Update:

If you want the spaces at row level, just add this CSS:

```
.rem-space-children { margin: 0 20px; }
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zfh6Lmb/2/)

Comment: This works too, but not 100% When the last two images disappear, the rest of the images are not resized and centered. There was a typo in my HTML `hide-xs` is supposed to be `hidden-xs`. I coppied the wrong code. It's fixed now

Comment: try changing `xs` to `sm` or `md`. It still breaks. It's weird though, that it does not get adjusted because it should.

Comment: It doesn't get adjusted because `col-sm-2` has `width: 16.6667%` defined.  That doesn't change if those elements are hidden or not.  It shouldn't be adjusted on bootstrap's account.  That doesn't change if you remove my changes or not.

Comment: Crap you're right.. I will have to come up with a fix for that then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the img tags with .row class like this.

```
    <div class="row top-shows">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 hide-xs"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 hide-xs"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
    </div>
```

Check the sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dyaa/fr656ykv/

**and if you want to center it so you'll only have padding in the first and the last one try this one**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row top-shows">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 hide-xs"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 hide-xs"><div class="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x600" class="img-responsive"/></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check the sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dyaa/fr656ykv/1/

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't want your solution to be intrusive, try this:**

```
   .row.top-shows > .col-sm-2 {   // or .row.top-shows > [class^="col-"] for any col- classes
      padding:0px !important;   
      margin :0px !important;
    }
```

> This will achieve your goal without a need to modify the current `html` structure.
>   This is also a exclusive method, no other elements will be touched by the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Fully CSS solution:

```
.top-shows {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.top-shows [class^="col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5679/)